# Appium- node.js - I am using this touch function and want to tap on this specific coordinate.But it gives me an error

Tags: node.js, automation, appium, appium-android

`driver.touchAction({actions: 'tap', x: 269, y: 1605})`

**Error:**

**unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown action undefined**

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this:
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(Mobiledriver);
action.tap(PointOption.point(269, 1605)).perform().release();